# Client is unable to finish the security negotiation within the configured timeout

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, timeout

I am making a WCF service and its WPF client. When I run the service from Visual Studio 2010 it publish the service to asp.net development server. My WPF client works fine with asp.net development server, but when I publish the service to IIS 7.0 it publish correctly .When I add service reference to my WPF client, the client successfully add new service reference with address of IIS. But when I call the WCF service methods from my WPF client, it give the following error.

"Client is unable to finish the security negotiation within the configured timeout (00:00:59.9239957).  The current negotiation leg is 1 (00:00:59.8789931).  "

How I can remove this error, there is no help available on net.

Comment: What security are you using in your service? What binding are you using? Is WPF application running on the same machine as IIS?

Comment: Are you using Https or some kind or certificates ?